# trigger update value before insert pl/sql-oracle

Tags: oracle

```
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
21/25    PL/SQL: ORA-00927: missing equal sign
22/2     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
22/31    PL/SQL: ORA-00927: missing equal sign
26/1     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
27/13    PL/SQL: ORA-00927: missing equal sign
32/1     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
33/13    PL/SQL: ORA-00927: missing equal sign
38/1     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
39/13    PL/SQL: ORA-00927: missing equal sign
44/1     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

I want to create a trigger when I insert into the table the value of 4 subject it will calculate automatically percentage and set scholarship discount like if student got **60%** then set some rupees discount and if **80%** than set some rupee discount

Comment: Where is your code? Will not be able to help with error only.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER vi_insert
 before  update ON student
 FOR EACH ROW
 ENABLE
declare
t student.total%type;
p student.percentage%type;
d student.discount%type;
vs1 student.s1%type;
vs2 student.s2%type;
vs3 student.s3%type;
vs4 student.s4%type;
vrno student.rno%type;
cursor stu is select * from student;
rw stu%rowtype;
begin
open stu;
loop

fetch stu into rw;


t:=rw.vs1+rw.vs2+rw.vs3+rw.vs4;
p:=t*0.25;
update student set total:=t where rno:=rw.rno;
 update student set percentage:=p where rno:=rw.rno;

Comment: if (r.p>=95)
 then
update student
set discount:=25000 where rno:=rw.rno;

-----cond 2
elsif (r.p>=90)
 then
update student
set discount:=20000 where rno:=rw.rno;

---cond 3
elsif (r.p>=80)
 then
update student
set discount:=15000 where rno:=rw.rno;

---cond 4
elsif (r.p>=75)
 then
update student
set discount:=10000 where rno:=rw.rno;

---- cond 5
else 
update student
set discount:=0 where rno:=rw.rno;
 
 end if;
exit
exit when stu%notfound;


end loop;
close stu;
vi_insert;
end;

Comment: and i am new here on this site sir .i was unable to set code in given format as per site instruction

Comment: In `WHERE`, use `=`, not `:=`

Comment: ok thanks i am trying

Comment: improve code formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write simple `BEFORE INSERT` Trigger. You don't even need to have a cursor. Try below trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER stud_percent_disc
BEFORE INSERT
ON student
FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
    v_total student.total%type;
    v_percent student.percentage%type;
    v_discount student.discount%type;
  BEGIN
    -- calculate total
    v_total := ( :new.s1 + :new.s2 + :new.s3 + :new.s4 );
    -- calculate percentage
    v_percent := ( v_total * 0.25 );
    -- calculate discount value
    if (v_percent >= 95) then
      v_discount := 25000;
    elsif (v_percent >= 90) then
      v_discount := 20000;
    elsif (v_percent >= 80) then
      v_discount := 15000;
    elsif (v_percent >= 75) then
      v_discount := 10000;
    else
      v_discount := 0;
    end if;
    :new.total := v_total;
    :new.percentage := v_percent;
    :new.discount := v_discount;
  END;
/
```

User below syntax for insertion:

```
insert into student(s1,s2,s3,s4,total,percentage,discount) values(88,88,88,88,0,0,0);
```

Comment: but after running this trigger when i am inserting the value in the table student like values in s1 s2 s3 s4 then no update perform in total ,percentage and discount

Comment: Is trigger created successfully ? or there were some errors ?

Comment: YES SUCCESFULLY CREATED

Comment: WHEN I USe after insert showing error                                                                               ORA-04091: table SYSTEM.STUDENT is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.STUD_PERCENT_DISC", line 5
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.STUD_PERCENT_DISC", line 8
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.STUD_PERCENT_DISC'

Comment: but using before update ...then no error but updation not performed by trigger ...like total,percentage,discount

Comment: insert into student(s1,s2,s3,s4) values(88,88,88,88);

Comment: Try with updated answer. Drop old trigger. Then create this one and use insert syntax shown in my answer.

Comment: drop trigger then   create trigger successfully  when giving value it stores bu no action performed only value showing...no total no discount ...no percentage .. also

Comment: But whether your insert worked as per expectations ?

Comment: Have you tried- `insert into student(s1,s2,s3,s4,total,percentage,discount) values(88,88,88,88,0,0,0);` ? What is the error ?

Comment: when tried ,all value save into table but no action performed based on total percentage discount

Comment: Sure. Welcome. :)